# <a`routerLink`> does not navigate to the desired route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am learning angular routing.
When I click on the `Home/About/Dashboard` link buttons (test.component.html) they display correctly `<module> works!` appropriately using `outlet1` `router-outlet`. But when I click on `Experiment` link button the display does not happen. What am I doing wrong?

My app.components.html looks like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
  </h1>
  <nav>

</nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet name="outlet1"></router-outlet>
```

My app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.gard';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';


const myModule = () => import('./my-routing/my-module').then(x => x.MyRoutingModule);
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TestComponent },
  { path: 'experiment', loadChildren: myModule },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent, outlet: "outlet1"
  },
  {
    path: 'about', canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: AboutComponent, outlet: "outlet1",
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent, outlet: "outlet1"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My my-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ListComponent } from '../list.component';
import { TestComponent } from '../test/test.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: ListComponent, outlet: "outlet1" },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyRoutingModule { }
```

My test.component.html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ outlet1: ['home'] }}]" routerLinkActive="active"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Home</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ outlet1: ['about'] }}]"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          About</button></a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
      <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ outlet1: ['dashboard'] }}]"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Dashboard</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ outlet1: ['experiment'] }}]"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Experiment</button></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using `forRoot` in two angular modules. That doesn't seem right... Also, the relative path would be `experiment/experiment` because it's a lazy loaded feature module with no top level empty route or defaults configured

Comment: I fixed `forRoot` in my-routing.module.ts

Comment: Where should I fix `experiment/experiment` - I mean which place in which code?

Comment: It would be the target of the routerLink's  outlet1 property.

Comment: So should it look like `<a [routerLink]="['experiment/experiment', { outlets:{ outlet1: ['experiment'] }}]"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Experiment</button></a>`

Comment: @Aluan Haddad - could you please be a little bit more specific - which part of code do I change?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration in `my-routing.module.ts` is not correct. You configured the path for your feature module in `app-routing.module.ts` like

```
{ path: 'experiment', loadChildren: myModule }
```

and then you configure one path in `my-routing.module.ts` like

```
{ path: 'experiment', component: ListComponent, outlet: "outlet1" }
```

Like @janci already mentioned in comments your route should look currently like 'experiment/experiment' to show the `ListComponent`.

Why?

With the first 'experiment' the Angular router navigates to your feature module `my-module`. In your feature module is no root path (empty path) configured, there is only a path 'experiment' configured, this is the second one in the mentioned path.

If you configure your route in `my-routing.module.ts` like

```
{ path: '', component: ListComponent, outlet: "outlet1" }
```

it should work as you expect it.

Comment: I changed in my-routing.module.ts to `{ path: '', component: ListComponent, outlet: "outlet1" }` but clicking on `Experiment` button still displays nothing. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: After the fix I have also noticed an exception `Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'experiment'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'experiment'`